# nagios4 20.04 from apt

Tags: 20.04

I have run Nagios on 18.04 - installing from source as all the help articles and Nagios itself ('standard') suggest (https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/quickstart-ubuntu.html).

I'm installing a new 20.04 server.
I noticed `nagios4` is available as a package via `apt` (4.3.4) so decided to try that.

There are a few differences with the "standard" package, including directory location (`/etc/nagios4`), but I got it to work except for authorisation.
The "standard" doc says to use `htpasswd` but `apt` is set to use `htdigest` in the Apache config.
The Nagios "services" HTML page shows my hosts, but HTTP, SSH notification is switched off. If I try to enable them I get

```
Sorry Dave, I can't let you do that...
It seems that you have chosen to not use the authentication functionality of the CGIs...
```

In `apache.conf` I have:

```
Require all    granted
#Require valid-user
```

which suggests access should allowed. But I switched them around anyway and restarted Apache.

I now get a `basic auth` dialog on that page, which when completed lets me run the enable command but I then get the `Sorry Dave` message.

In `cgi.cfg`, as installed, I have `use_authentication=0`, which the notes say is "off", although it says default is supposed to be non-zero. Setting this to `1`, however, stops access to the "services" page with:

```
It appears as though you do not have permission to view information for any of the services you requested...
```

If you believe this is an error, check the HTTP server authentication requirements for accessing this CGI and check the authorization options in your CGI configuration file.

There is no basic auth prompt.

Can this be resolved?
If we really do have to compile from sources, how can this broken one be removed from the package repo?

Comment: can you remind me which version of Apache you've got installed?

Comment: Hi @marc-vanhoomissen - its 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve the same problem following the instructions given in the `/etc/apache2/conf-available/nagios4-cgi.conf` file, that is, moving all the authentication directives directly under the `\<DirectoryMatch>...<\/DirectoryMatch>` section, simply commenting the 2 `<Files "cmd.cgi">` and `<\/Files>` tags.

This way every access to the Nagios web interface must be authenticated, but you can define different users and their respective permissions within Nagios' configuration.